# How can I disable and enable the textbox using with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have a text box

```
<input name="" type="text" id="txt" onblur="txt(this)"/>
```

and jquery

```
function txt(th) {
  $(th).hide().after('<span class=\"dfk\">' + $(th).val() + '</span>');  
}
```

I have done disable the textbox and dispaly the value of textbox but again click the value of the textbox. textbox should enable with the value.

Comment: Plz, try to reformulate the question. This looks very unclear to me. Cograts to someone who'll be able to answer it in this form:)

Comment: You mean you want to enable the textbox again once clicked? If yes, then why disable it in the first place?

Comment: It is pretty clear to me. It is likely a visibility thing

Comment: Actually, In first place textbox is enable ,if i enter the value and press the tab button. textbox will remove and display the value of the textbox. Again i click the value of the textbox, text box will display with value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do (if i understand what you need):

```
<input name="" type="text" id="txt" />

$('#txt').blur(function(){
    $(this).hide().after('<span class="dfk">' + $(this).val() + '</span>');  
});

    $('.dfk').live('click', function(){
       $(this).prev().show();
       $(this).remove();
    });
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qJ3sY/2/

Edit - i corrected to use the span

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cTTNF/)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt")
    .focus(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("txtOff").addClass("txtOn");
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("txtOn").addClass("txtOff");
    });
});
</script>    
<style>
.txtOn { border:1px solid black; background-color:light-grey}
.txtOff { border:1px solid white; background-color:white}
</style>
<input name="txt" type="text" id="txt" class="txtOff" value="" placeholder="Click to edit" />
```